# Module svc-ISAPI-4.0_32bit is returning 404

Tags: wcf, iis, isapi

I just started to see a 404.0 (i.e. a regular 404) response being reported from this handler.  However, I can find nothing wrong--there is no file permissions issue and the failed request log does not provide any clues.

Has anyone seen this?  What would be next steps for the investigation?

Comment: For WCF issues, IIS tools are less useful than WCF tracing, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing Enable it and the cause of such 404 errors should be obvious.

Comment: You can also check the Event Viewer to see if there are related error messages, or use the developer tools to view the error messages in the console.